# Adding Time offset to Marker expression

Tags: after-effects, after-effects-expressions

I have below expression on time-remap property which triggers transition based on the markers set on Action layer.

Is it possible to add certain frames of pre-roll to this expression so if the maker is set at 1 sec the transition start at 0.5 sec.

I have added n=1 so that it skips first marker as it does not require transition.
I have already tried replacing `t = m.key(n).time;` with `t = m.key(n).time-0.5;` which for some reason does not work.
Thank you!

```
    m = thisComp.layer("Action").marker;
    n = 1;
    if (m.numKeys > 1){
    n = m.nearestKey(time).index;
    if (m.key(n).time > time) n--;
    }
    if (n > 1){
    t = m.key(n).time;
    time - t ;
    }else
    0;
```

Comment: Anyone looking for solution ..just remove ```if (m.key(n).time > time) n--;```